# MSBUILD command to generate APPXUPLOAD file for cordova application from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Can you please guide me with the MSBUILD command line to build appxupload files for a cordova application built using Visual Studio 2015.

Am using the below command but its not generating the appxupload file.

msbuild windowsbuild.jsproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Windows-x64"  /p:AppxPackageIsForStore=true /p:BuildAppxUploadPackageForUap=true /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload

Also in case , I give multiple platforms, like Platform =windows-x86|Windows-x64|Windows-ARM, it gives me an invalid platform name error.

NOTE: Am able to successfully generate the app package using Project - > Create App Package option . I need to automate this outside of visual studio hence exploring the command line option.

Thanks for your help.

RAMYA M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the MSBUILD command that worked and generated the AppPackage.,

In the below command , if we change the CordovaBundlePlatforms=x86 OR CordovaBundlePlatforms=x64 , we can get platform specific AppPackage.

I required a single appxupload file for x86,x64 and ARM architecture

The output consists of ps1 file (to install on desktop) , appxbundle and .cer files and also a .appxupload file and I confirm that all of them are working fine.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" C:\Project\MyCode\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=release /p:Platform=arm /p:CordovaBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|arm"
Thanks for your inputs, appreciate the same.

Regards

RAMYA M

Answer (score 0):

> Am able to successfully generate the app package using Project - > Create App Package option . I need to automate this outside of visual studio hence exploring the command line option.

To manually create appxupload file, you need to create  `.appx` and `.appxsym` files first.

You can Create `.appx` file with [`MakeAppx.exe` Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).

`.appxsym` file is a compressed `.pdb` file.

Then you can create `.appxupload` file by following steps:

1. Place the `.appx` and the `.appxsym` in a folder
2. Zip the folder
3. Change the zipped folder extension name from `.zip` to `.appxupload`